# sending json requests in Python

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, python-requests, getjson, infinite-scroll

I am trying to send some json requests for scraping an infinite scroll box like this [link](http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/xom). Its json link is:

http://www.marketwatch.com/news/headline/getheadlines?ticker=XOM&countryCode=US&dateTime=12%3A00+a.m.+Nov.+8%2C+2016&docId=&docType=2007&sequence=6e09aca3-7207-446e-bb8a-db1a4ea6545c&messageNumber=1826&count=10&channelName=%2Fnews%2Fpressrelease%2Fcompany%2Fus%2Fxom&topic=&_=1479366266513

Some of the parameters are not neccesary and I created a dictionary of effective  parameters. For example,the parameter Count is the number of items that are shown in each scrolling. My code is :

```
import json
import requests

parameters = {'countryCode':'US','dateTime':'', 'docId':'','sequence':'6e09aca3-7207-446e-bb8a-db1a4ea6545c', 
         'messageNumber':'1826','count':'10','channelName':'', 'topic':'_:1479366266513' }
data = json.dumps(parameters)
firstUrl = "http://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/xom"
html = requests.post(firstUrl, params = data).text
```

My problem is that I cannot send the requests according to the parameters, when I remove all parameters, I get the same page (firstUrl link) as if I include all of them. Do you have any idea why it happens and how I can fix this problem?

Comment: I guess, content that you want to scrap couldn't be received via single request (even if you specify `count:1000`) as each time you make another scroll, your browser send new `XHR` request for another (10 entries) piece of data.

Comment: Thank you Anderson, my problem is that even without defining any parameter, I get the same result which is the main page and not the container that I am interested in(there are 3 different infinite scroll boxes and I am interested in one of them ), I am giving the parameters of that specific element but it couldn't detect it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `firstUrl` you are using is not correct. Moreover you should use `requests.get` instead of post. You should send the same parameters as in your link.

```
import json
import requests

parameters = {'ticker':'XOM', 'countryCode':'US','dateTime':'', 'docId':'','sequence':'6e09aca3-7207-446e-bb8a-db1a4ea6545c', 
         'messageNumber':'1826','count':'10','channelName':'', 'topic':'_:1479366266513' }
firstUrl = "http://www.marketwatch.com/news/headline/getheadlines"
html = requests.get(firstUrl, params = parameters)
print(json.loads(html.text)) # array of size 10
```

Comment: @ vtni : thank you so much, it works very well and I realle appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

`params` expects a Python dictionary, not a string, so you should directly pass `parameters`:

```
parameters = {'countryCode':'US','dateTime':'', 'docId':'','sequence':'6e09aca3-7207-446e-bb8a-db1a4ea6545c', 
         'messageNumber':'1826','count':'10','channelName':'', 'topic':'_:1479366266513' }

html = requests.post(firstUrl, parameters).text
```

Also, make sure that you should actually be using `post` and not `get`.

Comment: @DeepSpapce, thank you so much , I directly inserted parameters but it didn't change the result. when I change count from 10 to 100, I expect to get 100 items, but it's still the same.